# Performance difference between filling existing numpy array and creating a new one

Tags: python, numpy

In iterative algorithms, it is common to use large numpy arrays many times. Frequently the arrays need to be manually "reset" on each iteration. Is there a performance difference between filling an existing array (with nans or 0s) and creating a new array? If so, why?

Comment: The only way to know if there is a performance difference is to measure it.

Comment: There often is a big benefit in pre-allocating the necessary space for the results, if known in advance. Typically one would allocate it using `np.empty`. If smaller arrays are accumulated by the algorithm in a list, the final conversion to a big array may still be slower than the pre-allocation. This must have something to do with internal memory handling in numpy.

Comment: What's the purpose of the reset? Is it to set the array to some initial value (in which case NaN seems an odd value)? Otherwise there wouldn't be a need to reset the array, just overwrite whatever values exist during execution.

Comment: @Evert This is a general question. There are various reasons to set the array to an initial value (to 0s, for instance, if you are planning to build up the values by summation). Sometimes I use NaNs if the size of the array is a maximum and not all of it will necessarily be used. This allows differentiation of unused space and 0s/1s whatever put in place by the code.

Comment: I realised the question is more general, but I am actually curious about practical use cases. The summation example seems odd, since you initialize the values once, and not with every step of the iteration. The second example is something I was thinking about myself, where you need some sort of mask (possible with more than 2 on/off values), but I simply wondered about other cases.

Answer (score 6):

The answer depends on the size of your arrays. While allocating a new memory region takes nearly a fixed amount of time, the time to fill this memory region grows linear with size.
But, filling a new allocated memory with `numpy.zeros` is nearly twice as fast, as filling an existing array with `numpy.fill`, and three times faster than item setting `x[:] = 0`.

So on my machine, filling vectors with less than 800 elements is faster than creating new vectors, with more than 800 elements creating new vectors gets faster.

Comment: Daniel, any idea why `numpy.zeros` would be faster for larger arrays? Does the same occur with `numpy.ones`? (On my system btw, a MBA i5 and using `np.float` arrays, I break even around an array size of 20000. Also, `numpy.ones` is always slower than `numpy.fill(1)` for me, so it may be this break-even between `zeros()` and `fill(0)` only occurs for 0.)

Comment: only `zeros` has a special implementation. `ones` is implemented with `empty` and `fill(1)`.